# How can I reload a UIViewController with button action?

Tags: ios

I use a core data array and choose one question from that.

When I choose a question, I use a random number.

When a user hits the button to answer the question, I get a random number again to make a new question, so user can repeat answering.

I think it's possible if tapping on the answer button can reload the page.

How can I do that?

I try many ways but that way have problems.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

Comment: You need to identify what views and/or data in your view controller you want to reload.

Comment: it is UIViewController, and core data have words and image filename.

Comment: use collectionview to view your answer. And when tap or touch the button to give the answer then reload the collection view.

Comment: I think you should change your mind , in your case  updating your `UI` will be better than reloading `ViewController`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to reload / refresh views in ViewController

1. `setNeedsDisplay`
2. `setNeedsDisplayInRect`
3. Using `UITableView` / `UICollectionView` (as suggested by @Tan) as subview of UIViewContoller. Add all views in UITableView / UICollectionView and reload when required.
4. Lastly, I suggest that move complete code which you want to invoke into another method and invoke that method in both `viewDidLoad` and as well as  in your `buttonPressed` action.